# Working Backwards with the Quadratic Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently brushing on some of my basic Math skills, and been having trouble with using the Quadratic Formula.

Given:
$x_1 = \left(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}\right)$

And the quadratic equation in the form of:

$Ax^2 + Bx + C $ = 0

Shouldn't I get 0 when I substitute $x_1$, in the standard quadratic above?

$A{(\left(\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}\right))}^2 + B{(-b +  \left(\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}\right))} + C$

When I try to simplify this, I'm not getting 0, is my set up wrong?

*Edited equation because of formatting

Here's my work, maybe someone can point out my error?

If I let:

$ u = -b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$

$a\left(\frac{u}{2a}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{u}{2a}\right) + c$

$a\left(\frac{u}{2a}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{u}{2a}\right) + c\left(\frac{2a}{2a}\right)$

$\left(\frac{u^2}{4a}\right) + b\left(\frac{u}{2a}\right) + c\left(\frac{2a}{4a}\right)$

After here it gets a bit murky.

Comment: Explanation : the true formula is $x_1 =  \left(\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}\right)$

Comment: And be careful not to distinguish $A$ from $a$ or $B$ from $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$x_1 = \dfrac {-b  \pm  \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{ 2a} $

The $2a$ is common denominator for both terms. Then it will fix.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to verify that 
$$x = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
is a root of the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.  Substitution yields
\begin{align*}
ax^2 + bx + c & = a\left(\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right) + c\\
& = a\left(\frac{b^2 - 2b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} + b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}\right) + \frac{-b^2 + b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} + c\\
& = \frac{2b^2 - 2b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} - 4ac}{4a} + \frac{-b^2 + b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} + c\\
& = \frac{b^2 - b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} - 2ac}{2a} + \frac{-b^2 + b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} + c\\
& = \frac{-2ac}{2a} + c\\
& = -c + c\\
& = 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The formula is $\left(\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}\right)$. You can derive this using the method of completing the squares.

Answer (score 0):

I'll derive the quadratic formula instead of verifying it, as I think it is less messy.

Start with the substitution $x=\mu-\frac b{2a}$.

$$\begin{align}
0 & =ax^2+bx+c \\
& =a\left(\mu-\frac b{2a}\right)^2+b\left(\mu-\frac b{2a}\right)+c \\
& =a\mu^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\tag{expand and simplify} \\
\end{align}$$

$$0=a\mu^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

$$a\mu^2=\frac{b^2}{4a}-c\tag{isolate $\mu$}$$

$$4a^2\mu^2=b^2-4ac$$

$$(2a\mu)^2=b^2-4ac$$

$$2a\mu=\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

$$\mu=\frac{\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$x=-\frac b{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

> $$\boxed{x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}$$